# Find the startpage of current web using javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, welcome-page

I want to hide a "div" from all startpages/welcomepages. But I cant just compare "start.aspx" and my url parameter cause sometimes the page "start.aspx" isn't there in the url. Is there a way to know if I'm on a "startpage" or not using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, unfortunately it didnt work for me since there where something wrong with my SP.Publishing reference.

Instead I fixed it with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts") > -1) {
       $(".ms-breadcrumb-top").show()
   }
   else {
       $(".ms-breadcrumb-top").hide();
   }
}
```

All pages accept welcomepages are located in the _layouts for me so I'll just hide my element if it's not in the _layouts folder. Works like a charm so far.

Answer (score 1):

`SPWeb` has `RootFolder` which internally has `WelcomePage` property. You can use that to get this information

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var spWeb = clientContext.get_web();
var rootFolder = spWeb.get_rootFolder();
clientContext.load(rootFolder, 'WelcomePage');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert(rootFolder.get_welcomePage());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('error');
}
```

**In case of publishing web**

```
var web = context.get_web();
var pubWeb = SP.Publishing.PublishingWeb.getPublishingWeb(context, web);
context.load(pubWeb, 'DefaultPage');
```

Comment: It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested?

Comment: Not sure. Its working perfectly on my SP2013. By the way is it a publishing site?

Comment: Yes its a publishing site. Does it matter?

Comment: Yes. In that case we should get the `Publishing Web` and then use the `DefaultPage`

Comment: @Hannes I have edited my answer.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'PublishingWeb' of undefined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19180/discussion-between-hannes-and-amal-hashim).